# Step Connected if and only if Connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

A space $X$ is *step connected* if given any open covering $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ and any pair of points $p,q\in X$ there is a finite sequence $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ of sets belonging to $\mathcal{U}$ so that $p\in U_1$, $q\in U_n$ and $U_i\cap U_{i+1}\neq\emptyset$ for $1\leq j\leq n-1$.

Prove that a space is step connected if and only if it is connected.

So far I was able to prove that step connected implies connected by showing the negation, that disconnected implies not step connected.  Which was pretty straight forward by taking the open cover to be the partition of $X$ into open sets.  The other implication I am struggling with.  My first thought was to fix a $q\in X$ and let $A$ be the set of points such that this step sequence can be found.  Then showing $A$ is open, closed, and nonempty thus by $X$ being connected we would see that $A$ is all of $X$ and thus $X$ is step connected.  I was able to show that $A$ is open and nonempty, but cannot seem to show that $A$ is closed.  Any tips?

Also this isn't for a homework assignment, I am trying to prepare for an upcoming qualifying exam.

Comment: Show that $A$ is closed by showing that its complement is open.

Comment: That was my first thought.  I attempted to show that any point in the complement was contained in an open set that was a subset of the complement.  Do you have any advice on why any point in an open set around a not step connected point must also be not step connected?  I couldn't think of an argument that excluded the possibility that those points are in a different open set which can be step connected to the original point.

Comment: Suppose $x\notin A$. Choose $U\in\mathcal U$ such that $x\in U$. Assume that $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$. Choose $p\in A\cap U$. Since $p\in A$, $\mathcal U$ contains a step-sequence $U_1,\dots,U_n$ connecting $q$ to $p$. Then $U_1,\dots,U_n,U$ connects $q$ to $x$.

Comment: That makes sense.  I think I have it now.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: [Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973733/proof-of-theorem-26-15-in-general-topology-by-willard).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but here's a completely intuitive proof.

Take any topological space $X$ that is not step-connected.

Let points $p,q$ in $X$ and open cover $U$ of $X$ witness that $X$ is not step-connected.

Let $S$ be the set of all points in $X$ connected to $p$ via a step-sequence in $U$.

Let $T$ be the set of all points in $X$ connected to $q$ via a step-sequence in $U$.

Then $S,T$ are open sets, since each is a union of open sets.

And $S,T$ are disjoint, otherwise $p,q$ are connected via a step-sequence in $U$.

Let $R = X - ( S \cup T )$.

Let $V$ be the union of all open sets in $U$ that contains some point in $R$.

Then $V$ contains $R$, since $U$ is an open cover of $X$.

And $S,T,V$ are disjoint, since no point in $R$ is connected to $p$ or $q$ via a step-sequence in $U$.

Therefore $S,T \cup V$ witness that $X$ is disconnected.