# Proof of theorem 26.15 in "General Topology" by Willard

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> **26.14 Definition.** A *simple chain* connecting two points $a$ and $b$ of a space $X$ is a sequence $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ of open sets of $X$ such that $a\in U_1$ only, $b\in U_n$ only, and $U_i\cap U_k\neq\varnothing$ iff $|i-j|\leqslant1$.
>
> ***2.6.15 Theorem.*** If $X$ is connected and $\scr U$ is any open cover of $X$, then any two points $a$ and $b$ of $X$ can be connected by a simple chain consisting of elements of $\scr U$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $Z$ be the set of all points of $X$ which are connected to $a$ by a simple chain of elements of $\scr U$. Then $Z$ is obviously an open st and, since $a\in Z$, $Z$ is nonempty. We can prove the theorem by showing $Z$ is closed.
>
> $\quad$ Let $z\in\bar Z$. Then $z\in U$ for some $U\in\scr U$ and, $\color{brown}{\text{since $U$ is open, $U\cap Z$ contains }}$ $\color{brown}{\text{some point $b$}}$. Now $a$ is connected to $b$ by a simple chain $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ of elements of $\scr U$. If $z\in U_k$ for some $k$, then the smallest such $k$ produces a simple chain $U_1,\ldots,U_k$ from $a$ to $z$. If $z\notin U_k$ for any $k$, pick the smallest $l$ such that $U_1\cap U\neq\varnothing$ (e.g., $n$ is such an $l$). Then $U_1,\ldots,U_l$, $U$ is a simple chain from $a$ to $z$. Either way, $z\in Z.\;\blacksquare$

From Willard S. General Topology.
I have trouble to understand why, in the $\rm\color{brown}{brown}$ part, the intersection can't be empty.
can anyone help?

Comment: It's the definition or a fundamental characterisation of $\overline{Z}$. $z \in \overline{Z} \iff U\cap Z \neq \varnothing$ for all neighbourhoods $U$ of $z$.

Comment: Isn't the definition of \overline{Z} is X-Z?  how can I get that U∩Z≠∅?  I couldn't find the definition you wrote.

Comment: No, in topology or analysis, $\overline{Z}$ denotes pretty universally the closure of $Z$. Using that to denote the complement is a bad idea already in other branches of mathematics, in topology that is downright evil. (Nevertheless, I've been told, there is a russian mathematician doing just that.)

Answer (score 2):

$\overline{Z}$ is the closure of $Z$, i.e the smallest closed set that contains $Z$ as a subset, or equivalently (one can show) the set of all $x$, such that every open set $U$ that contains $x$, intersects $Z$. So the statement follows from that last definition of the closure.